# Permissions denied when installing Node.js on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, node.js

I'm trying to install Node.js on an Nginx+Passenger+Ruby server running the following steps as user 'deploy':

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26.tar.gz
tar zxvf node-v0.10.26.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.26
sudo ./configure && make && make install
```

Everything goes fine until it gets to the final make step and ends with this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/node'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

What permissions need to be set on that dir for node to be able to install correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because with

```
sudo ./configure && make && make install
```

only the **./configure** phase is run as root, the rest of the commands as an ordinary user.

Alternatives:

```
sudo "./configure && make && make install"

sudo ./configure && sudo make && sudo make install

sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Or only run `make install` as root via `sudo` since the others do not need to be ran as root at all.

Comment: True that, but still I tend to run all those commands under the same user privileges. root or an ordinary user, not a mix-up. Not even sure why, but that's the way I operate.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen There's usually no reason to do that, you can configure and make a program perfectly fine in a local user directory, but once you want to install, it needs root privileges to write stuff to the (/usr)/bin and /etc directories and such.